# Ability to tell autoformatter to respect how I multipline split html attributes in VS Code

Tags: html, vue.js, visual-studio-code, attributes, prettier

I have a problem in VS Code using Prettier for autoformatting JS and Vue code.

For example, how to set it to save this:

```
<Todo 
  v-for="todo in todos" 
  :key="todo.id" 
/>
```

as is - meaning on multiple line, one per each attribute?

So far if I do it like that and press cmd + s it will reformat it to this:

```
<Todo v-for="todo in todos" :key="todo.id" />
```

This is what I currently have in settings.json:

```
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
  "html.format.wrapAttributes": "force-expand-multiline",
  "[vue]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
  },
  "[javascript]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
  }
```

Any idea how make VS Code respect when I manually decide to split attributes in my .vue files each on a new line?

Answer (score 1):

Enable Prettier's [`singleAttributePerLine` option](https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html#single-attribute-per-line) in `<projectRoot>/.prettierrc` (create file if needed):

```js
// .prettierrc
{
  "singleAttributePerLine": true
}
```

If you prefer a global configuration for all projects, create `$HOME/.prettierrc` with the config above. A minor inconvenience when using the global config is that the Prettier extension only reads `$HOME/.prettierrc` once at startup. Any changes to that file would require an IDE restart to re-register the config.